# Pending method invocation for a game

Tags: java, android

I need to do pending methods invocation in Java (Android) in my game project. A method represents actions in a scene.

Maybe you're familiar with `Context.startActivity` in Android, which is not suddenly starting the activity, but statements below it is still executed before starting the requested activity. I've found 3 ways, but I'm not sure which one should I choose by considering the performance and PermGen issues (actually I don't know whether Android has PermGen issue if there are so many classes). These methods will not be called very frequent, may be once in 5 seconds, but may be they will be very many (there are so many scenes).

Please suggest the best way of doing this, by considering memory usage (maybe PermGen too), performance, ease of coding, and bug freedom.

**Using switch-case**

I need to add each method call in switch-case.

```
public class MethodContainer {

    public void invoke(int index) {
        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            method0();
            break;
        .
        .
        .
        case 100:
            method100();
            break;
        }
    }

    private void method0() {
        ...
    }

    .
    .
    .

    private void method100() {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Using for-loop and annotation/reflection**

Like the above, but make coding easier (except in defining constants).

```
public class MethodContainer {

    private static final int METHOD_0 = 0;
    ...
    private static final int METHOD_100 = 100;

    public void invoke(int index) {
        for (Method m : MethodContainer.class.getMethods()) {
            MyAnnotation annotation = m.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
            if (annotation != null && annotation.value() == index) {
                try {
                    m.invoke(this);
                    break;
                } catch (...) {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @MyAnnotation(METHOD_0)
    private void method0() {
        ...
    }

    .
    .
    .

    @MyAnnotation(METHOD_100)
    private void method100() {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Using inner classes**

There's no need to declare constants and no reflection, but too many classes.

```
public class MethodContainer {

    public void invoke(Runnable method) {
        method.run();
    }

    private Runnable method0 = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            ...
        }
    };

    .
    .
    .

    private Runnable method100 = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            ...
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example (switch-case) is so poorly thought of in the Object Oriented community that there is a refactoring designed specifically to replace it with your third implementation: [Replace Conditional With Polymorphism](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism).

To be honest, I would have never thought of your second implementation. It isn't completely heinous, though I would probably use the constructor to create an array of method objects that you can index into directly - rather than run through a for loop every time you want to make a call.

Between a revised second implementation (array with annotation/reflection) and the third implementation (inner classes) I would personally be more fond of the "inner class" version. I don't think that memory or performance is going to be a factor at this level and I think the third, inner class, version is much more readable (at least in Java - in other languages, you could implement something like the second approach directly).

Comment: I've chosen "inner class" version as you've recommended. I've found it made me easier to maintain and extend the code.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not too familiar with Android.

I wouldn't optimize for permgen space unless there is a good reason for it. It seems [premature optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/80092/36726). "[Permgen stores the methods of a class (including the bytecodes)](https://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/presenting_the_permanent_generation)" in all of your cases so I do not think that only the class definition headers would cause too much overhead.

From the three option the third is the most OOP (+1 to Donald). If it's possible try to make these classes static inner classes (*Effective Java, 2nd Edition, Item 22: Favor static member classes over nonstatic*). If they use fields from the parent class consider passing a context object to them instead of direct access. It would result looser coupling. ([Disadvantages of coupling on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_science%29#Disadvantages))